# "undefined reference" error in a very very simple c++ program

Tags: c++, linker, header-files, undefined-reference

I have a simple program, which I copied exactly from the example in http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/ because I'm learning how to make c++ programs with multiple files.

The program compiles but when building, the following error appears:

/tmp/ccm92rdR.o: In function main:
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here's the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h" // this brings in the declaration for add()

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

add.h

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y); // function prototype for add.h

#endif
```

add.cpp

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The code is almost perfect. Include `add.h` in `add.cpp`. Compile it as `g++ main.cpp add.cpp` and it will produce `a.out`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is almost perfect.

Add a line `#include "add.h"` in `add.cpp`.

Compile the files together as `g++ main.cpp add.cpp` and it will produce an executable`a.out`

You can run the executable as `./a.out` and it will produce the output "The sum of 3 and 4 is 7" (without the quotes)

Comment: Thank you, Arun Saha, it worked perfectly. By the way, will I always have to compile together all the files I have in my program or is there an easier way?

Comment: You are welcome! You can compile each `.cpp` files separately into `.o` files respectively and finally link all the `.o` files to a single executable. Steps are: `1) g++ -c main.cpp 2) g++ -c add.cpp 3) g++ main.o add.o`. However, once this quickly becomes tedious. In such  situation, a tool is used to manage the compilation and linking of files. The tool is called **`make`** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) It works based on a configuration file, typically named `Makefile`, which you have to provide. You can search for and start with a simple `Makefile`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was searching other websites for a simple straight answer but wasn't finding anything useful. I'll try that tool. :)

Answer (score 0):

Undefined references may happen when having many .c or .cpp sources and some of them is not compiled.

One good "step-by-step" explanation on how to do it is [here](http://gittup.org/tup/ex_a_first_tupfile.html)